# Is it possible to view screen session output?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, gnu-screen

I've created a session in screen. It produced some output. Now I want to see it. So I attached the needed session, but could only see output limited by the size of console size. If I scroll up I see previous console commands, not screens output. If I try to navigate using arrows then just arrow keys codes are inserted.
Is there any way to get the output of the screen session?
Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use the scroll-back buffer in screen.  You can navigate the scroll-back buffer by using `Ctrl-a Esc` or `Ctrl-a [` then you can page up/down with any of these actions:

http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Movement

`Ctrl-b` or `Ctrl-f` to move back and forth by a page.

`Esc` will pop you back out of scroll-back navigation.

Comment: Why does it ignore one symbol after Esc Esc?

Comment: whoops that's a mistake, you should only need one Esc to exit scroll-back mode. (corrected above)

Comment: Ctrl-a [ 

It works